# How to set Session config in Tensorflow Java API?

Tags: java, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to run Tensorflow in Android, using Tensorflow's Java API. I'm wondering how to set the Session config when creating a Session object.

In the Python API, you can do this by using the "config" option of the Session constructor ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session)).
But in Java API, I don't see such an option in the Session constructor ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Session)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent change made this possible ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b4eca4/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/Session.java#L56)). You can provide a serialized `ConfigProto` protocol buffer and provide it to the `Session` constructor.

However, since this was a recent change, you'll have to either build the Java API from source or wait for the next release (TensorFlow 1.1)

Comment: This looks like what I need. Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try!